# mmap and access to GPIO config registers in an ARM processor

Tags: arm, mmap

Im struggling to read(and write) to HW registers from Linux user space. The goal is to configure some GPIO pins from and be able to set and read this pins.

According to the spec for the processor(imx27 from Freescale) the physical address for the register bank controlling GPIO this is 0x10015000

My assumption was that I could use something like this:

```
unsigned long *gpio;
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
gpio = (unsigned long *) mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x10015000);
```

I now expected to be able to read and set data to the registers in the processor. The problem is that it does not matter which location I read, I always get 0.

For example register in physical location 0x10015220 contains a register showing which pins are in us as GPIO. This Defaults to 0xFFFFFFFF. Reading this register I expected to get something different than 0:

```
printf("PTC_GIUS: 0x%08lX\n", gpio[0x220]);
```

gives `PTC_GIUS: 0x00000000`.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: If gpio is 0x10015000 and is type unsigned long *, gpio[0x220] isn't reading what you think it is, probably.

Answer (score 4):

The `mmap` on `/dev/mem` should work. Have you tried running your code as root? Maybe some security is preventing your program from accessing the address-space. Also make sure you've passed the correct physical address of your GPIO-Space.

The approach you've used works on my Cortex-A8 ARM-board running linux without problems.

If you can't get it working there is not much you can do except finding or writing a device-driver for the gpio (writing one is not *that* hard btw.).

With a bit of luck someone already did that for you. Does a node named `/dev/gpio` exist in your filesystem? If so you already have a driver.

A google search on `/dev/gpio` will give you all details on how to use it. You may also find the source for a simple gpio driver that you can modify to suit your needs.

Comment: Yeah, it's often best to write a device driver, at least once past the prototyping stages.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you're using a kernel source code from 2009 and on, you should open `/dev/mem` with the `O_SYNC` flag set, if you want your memory access to be uncached.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version of the Linux kernel it may be blocking access to the `/dev/mem` device.  User mode access to that device is deprecated and dangerous.  It is used mainly for user mode access to video memory within X.  In embedded projects it can be useful to have access to memory mapped hardware (like GPIO).

Check your Kernel compile flags for `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` or other flags that restrict access to `/dev/mem`. It could be mistakenly blocking access to this memory range.

However, as Nils mentioned the best solution is to find a gpio module for the iMX27 or write your own.

Comment: Many folks recommend mapping the register using `/dev/mem`. What are the alternatives if we should avoid `/dev/mem` in userland?